# Beautiful Soup returning empty html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So this is my second question regarding Beautiful Soup (sorry, im a beginner)

I was trying to fetch data from this website:

https://www.ccna8.com/ccna4-v6-0-final-exam-full-100-2017/

My Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.ccna8.com/ccna4-v6-0-final-exam-full-100-2017/'

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")

print(page_soup)
```

But for some reason it returns an empty string.

I've been searching for similar threads and apparently it has something to do with the website using external api's , but this website doesn't.

[image: network of website]

Comment: If you `print(page_html)`before feeding it to be, does it give you the full html page you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the content-type of the response if gzip so you need to handle that before you can process the html response.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import gzip

url = 'https://www.ccna8.com/ccna4-v6-0-final-exam-full-100-2017/'

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = gzip.decompress(uClient.read())
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
print(page_soup)
```

Comment: that worked, thank you! Where did you see the gzip content-type tho? I debugged the response from the website and it tells me the content-type is "'text/html; charset=UTF-8'".

Comment: it should be on the requested page itself, the one you posted is incorrect as it is a request to wp-embed.min.js

Answer (score 2):

try using `requests` module

**Ex:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.ccna8.com/ccna4-v6-0-final-exam-full-100-2017/'

uClient = requests.get(url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.text, "lxml")
print(page_soup)
```

Comment: thank you, works now! Could you explain the difference though?

Comment: @DravenMainxd The site broadcasts a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. Requests decodes the content based on that header, while `urllib` just returns the content as it is recieved. You can get the same response content with `requests` if you use [`.raw`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)